# Tableau WDC and Javascript promises

Tags: javascript, tableau-api, es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

I'm (trying to) building a Tableau Web Data Connector (WDC) which needs to hit an external API and run a bunch of requests that are dependant on each other. However, I'm hitting a problem with populating multi data tables. My code in the example below works fine with a single table, but it won't populate the data for my second "timeUrlTable" table. I think it something to do with the way in which the promises are being handled.

The data is being returned correctly and I can see it using `console.out(tableData)` however for the second table it never gets rendered into the table in the WDC simulator.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```js
(function () {
    var myConnector = tableau.makeConnector();

  myConnector.getSchema = function(schemaCallback) {
        let mag_place_cols = [{
            id: "Guid",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        }, {
            id: "DN",
            alias: "DN",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        }, {
            id: "Name",
            alias: "Name",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        }, {
            id: "Serial",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        }];

        let magPlaceTable = {
            id: "magPlace",
            alias: "Items",
            columns: mag_place_cols
        };

        let time_url_cols = [{
            id: "id",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        }, {
            id: "url",
            alias: "DN",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        }, {
            id: "time",
            alias: "Name",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        }];

        let timeUrlTable = {
            id: "timeUrl",
            alias: "Details",
            columns: time_url_cols
        };

        schemaCallback([magPlaceTable, timeUrlTable ]);
    };
  myConnector.getData = function (table, doneCallback) {

    const tableData = [];

    console.log("v2")

    getAPIKey('*****', '******')
      .then(data => {
          console.log(data.APIKey);
          let APIKey = data.APIKey;

          if (table.tableInfo.id === "magPlace") {

            getItems(APIKey)
              .then(data => {
                for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                  tableData.push({
                    'Guid': data[i].Guid,
                    'DN': data[i].DN,
                    'Name': data[i].Name,
                    'Serial': data[i].X509.Serial,
                  });
                }
                table.appendRows(tableData);
                doneCallback
                return table
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
            console.log(tableData)

          }


          if (table.tableInfo.id === "timeUrl") {

            console.log("This should be timeUrl: " + table.tableInfo.id);

            getItems(APIKey)
              .then(data => {

                  for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {

                    getCert(APIKey, data[i].Guid)
                      .then(data => {
                        tableData.push({
                          'id': data.ItemDetails.CN,
                          'url': data.ItemDetails.EnhancedKeyUsage,
                          'time': data.ItemDetails.Issuer,
                        });
                      });
                  }
                table.appendRows(tableData);
                doneCallback
                }
              )

              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
            console.log(tableData)

          }

        }

      );


  };

  tableau.registerConnector(myConnector);
})();


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitButton").click(function () {
        tableau.connectionName = "Feed";
        tableau.submit();
    })

});;


function getAPIKey(user, password) {

  let creds = { Username: user, Password: password };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      headers: '{"Content-Type": "application/json"}',
      url: "https://example.com/authorize/",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: JSON.stringify(creds),
      success: function (data) {
        resolve(data)
      },
      error: function (error) {
        reject(error)
      },
    })
  })
}


function getItems(APIKey) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-Api-Key": APIKey
      },
      url: "https://examples/?ParentDnRecursive=%123",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (data) {
        resolve(data.items)
      },
      error: function (error) {
        reject(error)
      },
    })
  })
}

function getItem(APIKey, guid) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-Api-Key": APIKey
      },
      url: "https://example.com/vedsdk/items/" + guid,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (data) {
        resolve(data)
      },
      error: function (error) {
        reject(error)
      },
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: You never actually *call* the `donecallback`? Although it looks like you shouldn't use that anyway and rather `return` a promise.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I thought I am returning a promise. Could you maybe indicate where I should do this please.

Comment: Add a `return` statement in the `getData` function so that it returns the promise created from the `then()` call on the `getAPIKey()` promise, and add `return` statements in the `then` callback function so that it returns the promises created in there. However, I have no idea whether tableau can actually deal with promise-returning functions or whether it does require callback style - check their documentation.

Comment: Thanks - still don't get what you mean here, sorry. Its strange because as per the Tableau docs "When you create multiple table schemas, the WDC API calls the getData function once for each schema. As a result, you need a way to change the call to the USGS Earthquake API for each table. The easiest way to do this is to use the table.tableInfo.id value that we set in the table schemas." Also, the first table is working OK and rendering the data, its just the second table thats causing the problem.